# Comparing sizes of sets of integers

Tags: order-theory

Is there a total preorder $\lesssim$ on the power set of $\mathbb Z$ such that:

1. $A<B$ if $A\subset B$ (proper subsets are smaller)
2. $1+A\lesssim 1+B$ iff $A\lesssim B$ (where $1+C = \{1+c:c\in C\})$ (shift invariance)
3. if $A\cap C=B\cap C=\varnothing$, then $A\lesssim B$ iff $A\cup C\lesssim B\cup C$ (additivity)?

The answer is positive if [(3) is dropped](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7295) or if (2) is dropped (easiest way for me to see it is by using an ultrafilter to create a hyperreal-valued finitely additive strictly positive measure on $\mathbb Z$). The answer is trivially positive with $\mathbb N$ in place of $\mathbb Z$: just use lexicographic ordering on the indicator functions.

If one adds reflection invariance ($-A\lesssim -B$ iff $A\lesssim B$), the answer is easily seen to be negative.

It's easy to show that such a comparison would have various weird properties, such as that it says that there are more positive odd numbers than positive even numbers, and that either: (a) $(-\infty,a]\cap\mathbb Z < [b,\infty)\cap\mathbb Z$ for all $a,b$ (it is biased to the right), or (b) $(-\infty,a]\cap\mathbb Z > [b,\infty)\cap\mathbb Z$ for all $a,b$ (it is biased to the left).

Comment: If I don't miss something, writing $f\lesssim g$ for all $f,g$ fulfills the condition. Do you have an additional non-triviality requirement?

Comment: Yeah: I meant $A<B$ in (1).

Comment: What about: $A\lesssim B$ iff $A=B$ or $\min(A\smallsetminus B)>\min(B\smallsetminus A)$ (with $\min(\emptyset)=+\infty$)?

Comment: I assume $\min$ is $\inf$, or else it's not defined for sets not bounded below. But then it's not a total (linear) order. Consider the evens and the odds. It becomes total if you replace $>$ with $\ge$, but I think last time I tried something like this, transitivity failed.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a total preorder. Indeed min is defined (since every nonempty subset of N has a min and for $A\neq B$ at least one of $A-B$, $B-A$ is nonempty). Assuming $0\in N$, for odd and even, min(ODD-EVEN)=1 and min(EVEN-ODD)=0 so EVEN$\le$ODD. Assuming $0\notin N$ (I don't know your convention), it yields ODD$\le$EVEN.

Comment: But the question is about subsets of $\mathbb Z$ not just of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't guess this. One is called "relative" integers and the other "natural" integers, if you don't want to use standard notation Z/N.

Comment: Interesting: I've never heard of "integers" as used for anything but $\mathbb Z$. I always say "naturals" for $\mathbb N$. I never heard "relative integers" before, but there are 6660 google hits for it, so it's a real phrase.

Comment: I've certainly heard "integers" for both.

Comment: I'm probably missing or misreading something, but if you can do it for $\mathbb N$, why can't you do it for every set which is in bijection with $\mathbb N$ (such as $\mathbb Z$) ?

Comment: @Vepir: Condition 2 is not preserved by bijections.

Comment: what about the approach with Zorns lemma on the set of preorders satisfying these conditions. If we say one preorder is larger than another, if it extends it, we can easily show that any totally ordered chain of preorders has an upper bound given by $A\le B$, if there is some preorder $\le'$ in the chain for which $A\le'B$ holds. It remains to show that any non-total preorder satisying your condition is not maximal, i.e. If we have two uncomparable sets, we can somehow construct a larger preorder in which these sets are comparable. I dont know whether the last step works.

Comment: That's a likely strategy: it's how one proves Szpilrajn's theorem, and how I proved the version without the additivity condition, but I don't know how to do the "last step" with it in place.

Comment: Interesting question. I have no idea about the answer, but I think condition (3) could be stated more neatly: $A\lesssim B$ iff $A\setminus B\lesssim B\setminus A$.

Comment: Without (2) I think the easiest way is to take an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on the set $S$ of all finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$ with the property that $\{F\in S:a\in F\}\in\mathcal U$ for every $a\in\mathbb Z$, and decree that $A\lesssim B$ iff $\{F\in S:|A\cap F|\le|B\cap F|\}\in\mathcal U$. Maybe that's the same as what you said, which I didn't actually understand.

Comment: Your way of proving this without 2 is a little more direct than what I had in mind. Nice!  And you're right about 3. My formulation comes from qualitative probability theory, where 3 is a common axiom mirroring Kolmogorov's finite additivity axiom.

Comment: I was getting ready to make a trivial comment. Now that the question is answered my comment seems redundant as well as trivial but I won't let that stop me. By a standard compactness argument the preorder you want on $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ exists iff every **finite** $\mathcal B\subset\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ admits a total preorder which satisfies your conditions as far as they are defined, e.g., (2) holds whenever $A,B,1+A,1+B\in\mathcal B$.

Comment: Moreover we may assume that $\mathcal B$ is a finite Boolean subalgebra of $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, and then so is $\mathcal B_0=\{A\in\mathcal B:1+A\in\mathcal B\}$. So it seems to me that the question is about a finite Boolean algebra $\mathcal B$ with given subalgebras $\mathcal B_0,\mathcal B_1$ and an isomorphism $f:\mathcal B_0\to\mathcal B_1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is such a preorder. I will argue that there is a preorder on the space of bounded functions $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ so that comparing indicator functions in this space does the job. A vector space preorder can be constructed from a suitable "positive cone", the set of non-negative elements, so the main task is to construct this cone.

Let $M$ be the set of non-negative, not identically zero, finitely-supported functions $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R.$ Let $B$ be the real vector space of bounded functions $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R.$ Let $a*\phi$ denote convolution of a function $a\in B$ by a function $\phi\in M.$ Define $a\sim b$ for $a,b\in B$ to mean that $a*\phi=b*\psi$ for some $\phi,\psi\in M.$ This is an equivalence relation because $M$ is a (commutative) monoid under convolution. The $\sim$-equivalence class $[0]$ of zero is a linear subspace of $B.$

Define a good cone to be a set $C\subset B$ such that

- C1. $y\in C\iff z\in C$ whenever $y\sim z,$ and
- C2. $C$ is a convex cone ($x,y\in C\implies \lambda x+\mu y\in C$ for $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$), and
- C3. $C\cap (-C)=[0].$

Define $C_0$ to be the set of $x\in B$ such that $x\sim y$ for some non-negative function $y\in B.$ Because non-negative functions are closed under convolution by any $\phi\in M,$ the definition of $C_0$ simplifies slightly to $x*\phi$ being non-negative for some $\phi\in M.$ The set $C_0$ satisfies the good cone conditions: (C1) is obvious, for (C2) if $x*\phi$ and $y*\psi$ are non-negative and $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$ then $(\lambda x+\mu y)*\psi*\psi$ is non-negative, and for (C3) if $x*\phi$ is non-negative and $x*\psi$ is non-positive, then $x*\phi*\psi$ is identically zero so $x\sim 0.$ By Zorn's lemma there is a maximal good cone $C$ containing $C_0.$

Consider $x\in B\setminus C.$ Define $C_x$ to be the set of $y\in B$ such that $y*\phi= x*\psi+c$ for some $\phi\in M$ and $\psi\in M\cup\{0\}$ and $c\in C.$ By maximality of $C,$ the set $C_x$ is not good.
(C1) holds: whenever $y*\eta=z*\zeta$ and $y*\phi= x*\psi+c$ we have $z*\zeta*\phi=x*\psi*\eta+c*\eta,$ which implies $z\in C_x.$
(C2) holds: if $y*\phi= x*\psi+c$ and $y'*\phi'= x'*\psi'+c'$ and $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$ then $(\lambda y+\mu y')*\phi*\phi'=x*(\psi*\phi'+\psi'*\phi)+(c*\phi'+c'*\phi).$
So (C3) fails: some $y\not\sim 0$ satisfies $y*\phi= x*\psi+c$  and $y*\phi'=-x*\psi'-c'.$  But then $$-x*\psi'*\phi-c'*\phi=y*\phi*\phi'=x*\psi*\phi'+c*\phi'$$
which implies $x*(\psi*\phi'+\psi'*\phi)+(c*\phi'+c'*\phi)=0.$ If $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are both zero, then $c*\phi=-c'*\phi$ is in $C\cap (-C)$ contradicting $y\not\sim 0.$ So $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are not both zero, which means $-x\sim c*\phi'+c'*\phi\in C.$
In other words $x\in -C.$

We have shown that $C\cup (-C)=B.$ The cone $C$ defines a total vector order on $B/[0],$ but to answer the question we just need to define $S\lesssim T\iff 1_T-1_S\in C.$ Your condition 1 comes from $C_0\subset C$ and (C3). Your condition 2 comes from (C1) - shifting is convolution by a delta function. Your condition 3 comes from $1_{T\cup U}-1_{S\cup U}=1_T-1_S$ whenever $S\cap U=T\cap U=\emptyset.$

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this generalizes to any abelian group $G$ in place of $\mathbb Z$, with (2) replaced by $x+A\lesssim x+B$ iff $A\lesssim B$ for all $x\in G$? Or is there some step that fails?

Comment: @AlexanderPruss: yes, it generalizes to give a total preorder on the powerset of any abelian group $G.$